# Indirect modification of overloaded property when building a PHPUnit test for Braintree webhook

Tags: php, symfony, testing, phpunit, braintree

I am trying to build a test with PHPUnit to test my Braintree hook. I have this test case which uses the dataProvider below:

```
/**
 * @covers SubscriptionExpiredHook::processHook()
 * @dataProvider dataProvider
 */
public function testProcessHook($subscriptionId)
{
    $subscriptionExpiredHook = new SubscriptionExpiredHook($this->siteManager);

    $notification = $this->getMockBuilder('Braintree\WebhookNotification')
        ->disableOriginalConstructor()
        ->getMock();

    $notification->subscription->id = $subscriptionId;

    $router = $this->getRouterMock();

    $subscriptionExpiredHook->setSubscription(new Subscription($router));

    $response = $subscriptionExpiredHook->processHook($notification);

    $this->assertEquals(200, $response->getStatusCode());
}

public function dataProvider()
{
    return [
        [
            'subscription_id' => 'CRM1872',
        ]
    ];
}
```

The line that is causing the problem is this:

```
$subscriptionId = $hook->subscription->id;
```

...and this is the error I get when I run the test:

> 1)
>   CRMPiccoBundle\Tests\Braintree\Hooks\SubscriptionExpiredHookTest::testProcessHook
>   with data set #0 ('CRM1872') Indirect modification of overloaded
>   property Mock_WebhookNotification_e65192ec::$subscription has no
>   effect

Is there a way that I can set the subscription id to allow this test to proceed or am I looking at it the wrong way?

Answer (score 1):

<sub>Full disclosure: I work at Braintree. If you have any further questions, feel free to contact [support](https://developers.braintreepayments.com/).</sub>

WebhookNotifications are not currently mockable, though making webhook testing more robust is on our roadmap. For the time being, use [`WebhookTesting::sampleNotification`](https://github.com/braintree/braintree_php/blob/37ecac0b1b848e1c47b5aaea0234501d012ec5bb/lib/Braintree/WebhookTesting.php#L6) to pack a `sampleNotification` with the type of the `WebhookNotification` as well as the `subscription_id`. You can view an example usage [here](https://developers.braintreepayments.com/guides/webhooks/testing-go-live/php#sample-payload-and-signature).

Note that `$webhookNotification->subscription` will not give you an entire object, and you will have to run a [find](https://developers.braintreepayments.com/reference/request/subscription/find/php) against your sandbox to retrieve the entire subscription.

Comment: Thanks, this is a helpful answer. However, I am having difficulty accessing the Braintree API from my tests. When I call `find` I get the following error - `Braintree\Exception\Configuration: Braintree\Configuration::merchantId needs to be set (or accessToken needs to be passed to Braintree\Gateway)`. I am using the CometCult BraintreeBundle and I wonder if PHPUnit is unable to access the params inside the services.yml in the vendor bundle - https://github.com/cometcult/CometCultBraintreeBundle/blob/master/Resources/config/services.yml#L7 . Tricky one to test...

Comment: I'm not familiar with CometCult BraintreeBundle, but that error is a pretty common and straightforward one. If you're sure that your `merchantId`,  `publicKey`, and `privateKey` are all set in your environment, then I would either open a new issue on Github or Stack Overflow, or send an email to support@braintreepayments.com. Usually these values are set in a `.env` file, but I don't know how your configuration is managed.

Comment: It looks like the equivalent to `.env` is [`app/config/config.yml`](https://github.com/cometcult/CometCultBraintreeBundle#configuration)